# Output only specific lines in unix

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I'm trying to remove lines from the output that contains "xyz" in 1st column using awk as

```
grep -H --with-filename "Rule" *| awk '$1!=" \*xyz\* "{print $0}'
```

but I'm not having any success with this.

For example after doing `grep -H --with-filename "Rule"` I'm getting the output as

```
file_xyz.log abc p12r
file1.log asd ef23t
fi_xyz.log gbc or26r
file1.log asd ef2t
```

but I want to remove all lines which contain `xyz`.

Comment: Try `grep -H --with-filename "Rule" * | awk '$1 !~ /xyz/ {print}'`

Comment: Using Bash's `extglob`: `grep -H rule !(*xyz*)`

Answer (score 1):

Some notes on your question:

1. What you have isn't very close to valid `awk` syntax, you should find an intro to `awk` tutorial or read a few pages of the manual to get started. I highly recommend everyone get the book `Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins`.
2. A glance at the `grep` man page will tell you that `-H` and `--with-filename` are the short and long versions of exactly the same option - you don't need to use both, just one of them.
3. The string `Rule` doesn't appear anywhere in the output you say you get when grep-ing for `Rule` and `grep -H` will output a `:` after the file name while you show a blank - make sure your input, output, and code are consistent and correct when asking a question.
4. The approach you're trying to use will fail for filenames that contain spaces.
5. You never need `grep` when you're using `awk`.

This is probably all you need:

```
awk '(FILENAME !~ /xyz/) && /Rule/{print FILENAME, $0}' *
```

but there are also ways in some shells (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164025/133219 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335484/133219 for `bash` examples) to specify a globbing pattern that excludes some strings so then you never open them to search inside in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
grep -H --with-filename "Rule" *| awk '$1 !~ /xyz/'
```